# Child Value counter upon making payment Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attaching the diagram of my firebase database. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11p5xmLjHC49sqzvXYo3Au5GdNnULdnom

I want to update the value of the key "eventsregistered" upon successful payment.

The sole requirement is to increase the number of registered events of the user upon successful payment. The Payment function is handled by me. The problem that i am facing is that i can change the value of the child upon payment but the counter resets to zero evry time I launch the app. Please provide me a solution with the proper code. I have tried using .setValue method but it didn't work out.

I have tried with the following code but it didn't work out.
The following function is executed when the payment is done. The logic seems to be okay but when i reset the app the value of the key is reset to zero for no reason that could be known by me.

The code is attached below

```java
int regEvents = 0;
String events_registered = "0";

private void btnAddRegisteredEvents() {
    final String key2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final DatabaseReference databaseReferenceObj2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("Users")
            .child(key2).child("eventsregistered");
    databaseReferenceObj2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            events_registered = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    regEvents = Integer.parseInt(events_registered) + 1;
    databaseReferenceObj2.setValue(String.valueOf(regEvents));
}
```

Please help me with this code and help me to update the counter of registered evets upon a successful payment. Just a reminder, the payment function is already handled by me. What is required is the code that increments the value of the key "registeredevents" after a successful payment.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because of the asyncronous nature of how the data is being retrieved from Firebase.  You need to make sure the read completes before you try to use its result.  As it is, you start the read, then immediately try to use the result.

But worse -- you aren't protected from someone else modifying the data at the same time after the read completes.  You need to do this in a transaction.

There is a [good example of a counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) in the documentation.  But its a little more complex than you need.  I think this will work for you in place of where you currently call `addValueEventListener` and the rest of the function:

```java
    databaseReferenceObj2.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            long newValue = 1; // If it doesn't exist, assume zero and increment to 1.
            String currentValue = mutableData.getValue(String.class);
            if (currentValue != null) {
                newValue = Long.parseLong(currentValue) + 1;
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(String.valueOf(newValue));
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
```

This is written to deal with the fact that you are currently storing this number as a string, but it probably makes more sense to store it as a number (e.g. a `Long`).